# How do I shorten super long variable labels of an SPSS file in R?

Tags: r, spss

**Context:**

- I have data from a large survey (from a Qualtrics survey, exported for SPSS, .sav file format).
- There are 648 variables total, because most of the questions were "check all that apply" or ranked response, where every option shows up as a binary variable.
- 200 variables (for the rank response questions) have variable labels that are VERY long and cumbersome. The first 150 or so words of the labels are the same for each label, containing the explanatory text for the question, and then the final 2-5 words of the label are different, containing the unique information for that variable.
- Currently using haven and labelled packages for reading in the .sav file and created a data dictionary.

**Problem:**
I would like to be able to remove the text from all these 200 variable labels that is the same, and be left with only the unique words at the end.

**Where I'm at:**

I'm able to locate all 200 variable names of interest here because they all contain "RANK", with the below:

```
colnames(
  look_for_and_select(data,
                      "RANK",labels=FALSE,
                      values=FALSE,
                      ignore.case=FALSE),
  )
```

Everything I'm finding in my searches are functions to replace or add a new variable labels, but I need to be able to retain the unique text already in the label. I think maybe there's a way to use gsub()... but would appreciate any ideas or help!

**Example:**
Here is the text in the variable label, with the final words I'd like to retain bolded at the end. Every variable label has this same huge block of text at the beginning, and a different 2-5 words at the end:

"1.5 Which actions present the greatest opportunity to advance this scenario's goal?   Select up to 3 of your previously selected actions, drag them into the box, and rank them in order of their importance for this goal (1=most important).     Scenario Context & Assumptions     Imagine yourself as a manager responsible for planning all street tree management on a hypothetical street in your region for the next 20 years. The street has a sidewalk and low-rise development, with buildings that are approximately 1-3 stories tall. In this mostly perfect world, you have full control over the trees adjacent to the sidewalk.    Within these scenarios, assume the following will be true:      Each action you select is in comparison to not doing the actions at all     Actions will be performed according to industry standard"   Trees will not be removed by events such as vandalism, new construction, extreme storms, or pest invasions  Newly planted trees will be watered through establishment and as needed for survival    Urban form will not change (street, pavement, buildings will remain the same with reasonable maintenance)   Species planted will be adapted for any change in hardiness zone projected in 20 years due to climate change - Ranks - Opportunities to achieve this scenario's goal (rank 3) - **plant native species**"

Comment: It would be useful if you added a few example names to your question and how you would want the result to look

Comment: good idea - added!

Comment: Thanks. Assuming that the string given in your question fits the same pattern as all the names: you can extract all the words after the final hyphen with `sub('.*-', '', string)` (where `string` is the vector of names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(labelled)
```

Create a `data.frame` with variable labels that resemble your description.

```r
same <-
  '1.5 Which actions present the greatest opportunity to advance this scenario\'s goal? Select up to 3 of your previously selected actions, drag them into the box, and rank them in order of their importance for this goal (1=most important). Scenario Context & Assumptions Imagine yourself as a manager responsible for planning all street tree management on a hypothetical street in your region for the next 20 years. The street has a sidewalk and low-rise development, with buildings that are approximately 1-3 stories tall. In this mostly perfect world, you have full control over the trees adjacent to the sidewalk. Within these scenarios, assume the following will be true: Each action you select is in comparison to not doing the actions at all Actions will be performed according to industry standard" Trees will not be removed by events such as vandalism, new construction, extreme storms, or pest invasions Newly planted trees will be watered through establishment and as needed for survival Urban form will not change (street, pavement, buildings will remain the same with reasonable maintenance) Species planted will be adapted for any change in hardiness zone projected in 20 years due to climate change - Ranks - Opportunities to achieve this scenario\'s goal (rank 3) - '

var_labels <- paste(same, "plant native species", 1:10)

var_names <- paste("var", 1:10, sep = "_")


df <-
  var_names |>
  lapply(\(x) tibble(a = 1:10) |> set_names(x)) |>
  bind_cols() |>
  set_variable_labels(.labels = var_labels)
```

We can use `labelled::get_variable_labels()` to obtain all variable labels
and then modify them with `stringr::str_remove()` with a Regular Expression
(RegEx), as suggested by user20650 in their comment.
The regular expression `.*-` instructs `str_remove()` to remove all characters
until it hits a final dash/hyphen. If all of the variable labels separate
the last bit with a dash, this should work across all labels.

```r
short_var_labels <-
  df |>
  get_variable_labels() |>
  str_remove(".*-") |>
  trimws()

short_var_labels
#>  [1] "plant native species 1"  "plant native species 2" 
#>  [3] "plant native species 3"  "plant native species 4" 
#>  [5] "plant native species 5"  "plant native species 6" 
#>  [7] "plant native species 7"  "plant native species 8" 
#>  [9] "plant native species 9"  "plant native species 10"
```

Now we can apply the short variable labels to the `data.frame`.

```r
df <-
  df |>
  set_variable_labels(.labels = short_var_labels)

get_variable_labels(df)
#> $var_1
#> [1] "plant native species 1"
#> 
#> $var_2
#> [1] "plant native species 2"
#> 
#> $var_3
#> [1] "plant native species 3"
#> 
#> $var_4
#> [1] "plant native species 4"
#> 
#> $var_5
#> [1] "plant native species 5"
#> 
#> $var_6
#> [1] "plant native species 6"
#> 
#> $var_7
#> [1] "plant native species 7"
#> 
#> $var_8
#> [1] "plant native species 8"
#> 
#> $var_9
#> [1] "plant native species 9"
#> 
#> $var_10
#> [1] "plant native species 10"
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm actually looking to edit the variable labels, not the variable names. Do you have an idea for how to modify this to edit the variable labels?

Comment: I just added an example in the question

Comment: I updated my answer to work for variable labels and made it specific to your case.

Comment: thank you! This was very helpful and I learned a lot.